# How to filter ChromeDevTools cURL correctly for Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl, cmd, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to check if I can access a page the same way in **cURL** as I can access it in **Chrome**.

With [ChromeDevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/replay-a-network-request-in-curl) you can copy the request as a cURL command depending upon your OS.

So I selected **Windows(cmd)**, which gave me roughly this command:

```
curl "https://practice.org/tracks/DSA/?batch=339" ^
  -H "authority: practice.geeksforgeeks.org" ^
  -H "cache-control: max-age=0" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua: ^\^" Not;A Brand^\^";v=^\^"99^\^", ^\^"Google Chrome^\^";v=^\^"91^\^", ^\^"Chromium^\^";v=^\^"91^\^"" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0" ^
  -H "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1" ^
  -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-site: none" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-mode: navigate" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-user: ?1" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-dest: document" ^
  -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9" ^
```

But when the 3rd header is encountered in Windows CMD the whole command is executed:

```
-H "sec-ch-ua: ^\^" Not;A Brand^\^";v=^\^"99^\^", ^\^"Google Chrome^\^";v=^\^"91^\^", ^\^"Chromium^\^";v=^\^"91^\^"" ^
```

**When the above line is encountered the whole command is executed without waiting for more input.**

**The formatting is not done correctly.**

I don't know much about Batch Programming in Windows, and have no way to correct the input.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: @KJ This did not work. Any other way I can get the proper escaped string ?

Comment: The website doesn't work.

Comment: @Reino Which website ?

Comment: "https://practice.org/tracks/DSA/?batch=339"